# Would this optical media question be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have had a few questions in the past about the longevity of optical media.  For example:

- [Do pressed disks CD/DVD ROMS have longer life than CD-R/DVD-R’s?](https://superuser.com/q/1180398/364367), which focused on the useful life of recorded data.
- [What is the shelf life of unused/unburned CD-R/CD-RW disks?](https://superuser.com/q/821702/364367), which focused on the shelf life of unrecorded discs.
- There have also been several questions on options for long-term archiving of data in general, that touched on optical media.

I recently encountered a high failure rate trying to write to some old DVD-Rs from unopened packages.  After a little research, it became clear that the shelf life of unrecorded DVD-Rs (and other recordable optical media) is much shorter than the archive life of data on them.  However, I couldn't find an explanation of why that is the case.

I'm thinking about writing a question with three objectives:

- Alert readers to the fact that the media has a much shorter shelf life before use that the expected service life of data recorded on them.
- Ask what, if any, characteristics can be used to identify discs with a longer unused shelf life (e.g., media layer color or package terminology).
- Ask for the technical reasons why the unused shelf life is so much shorter than the service life of data recorded on them (that's what has me intrigued).

I think such a question could be useful.  However, especially the last bullet 
might be viewed as more of a disc technology question, and potentially out of scope for the site.

Any thoughts about whether this would be on-topic (or other suggestions for the question)?

Comment: In my opinion it would be on-topic (including the last bullet point) and is also an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the encouragement.  It was a tough one to write, trying to keep it in-scope.  For anyone interested: [How to avoid unwritable CDs and DVDs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1221911/how-to-avoid-unwritable-cds-and-dvds).  Any suggestions are welcome (and answers, of course).